# Rust: Why isn't "self" a reference when "self: &Self"?

Tags: rust, reference, self

According to [Rust Lang Programming Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-03-method-syntax.html), we know that:

> The &self is actually short for self: &Self

However, from the example below (`fn get_name`), we wrote `self: &Self`, but `self` is not a reference but the object itself according to the error message. Why isn't `self` a reference in this case? What is the ampersand for in `&Self` then?

Example: a simple struct with method that returns a person's name

```
struct Person {
    name: String
}

impl Person {
    fn new(name: &str) -> Person {
        Person {
            name: name.to_string()
        }
    }

    fn get_name(self: &Self) -> &String {
        self.name // Error: expected `&std::string::String`, found struct `std::string::String`
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's complaining about `self` and not `self.name`?

Comment: `self` is a reference but `self.name` is not. You need to either return `&self.name` or change the return type to `String` and return `self.name.clone()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because of [automatic dereferencing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28519997/501250).

C has the `.` and `->` operators, where `.` is applied to values and `->` to pointers.  In C, `x->y` is exactly equivalent to `(*x).y`.

Rust has `.` but not `->`, so to make the syntax friendly, `.` will usually automatically dereference when the compiler cannot find the member requested.  In this case, `&Person` doesn't have a `name` attribute (since references can't have attributes), so the compiler tries again with a dereference (`(*self).name`) and it finds the attribute this time, on `Person`.

Since `*self` has type `Person`, `(*self).name` has type `String`.  To fix the problem, you take a reference to the string by doing `&self.name`, which means the same thing as `&((*self).name)` (extra parens added for clarity).

To directly address your question:

> ... `self` is not a reference but the object itself according to the error message. Why isn't `self` a reference in this case?

The error message only refers to the `String` attribute and doesn't really give you any information about `self` at all.  `self` is indeed a reference.  If you throw this in your `impl Person`:

```
fn test(&self) { self }
```

Then the compiler will tell you what `self` is (because it doesn't match the implied `()` return type):

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:12:18
   |
12 | fn test(&self) { self }
   |                - ^^^^ expected `()`, found `&Person`
   |                |
   |                expected `()` because of default return type
```

---

Note that you will see the same compiler error if you say `fn get_name(&self)`.  This error isn't caused by the `self: &Self` syntax; it is indeed equivalent to `&self`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I mistreated the error against `self.name` to `self`!

Comment: @JackLien Sometimes you just need another set of eyes on the problem!